# the 12 - word phrase dilemma

Tags: exodus

Just started with exodus. downloaded it and set up an account.
after a couple of days, I want to log in, but can't. The password doesn't work. When I want a prompt, I am asked for some 12- words -phrase that I never heard of before!
If I was never asked to set my 12-word-phrase before or given one (cause I don't know how it works, really) does it mean I never successfully started / opened my account?
the help guys didn't answer to my 2nd message....

Answer (score 1):

See

- https://support.exodus.io/article/37-how-do-i-get-started-with-exodus

> **Backup your wallet to keep it safe**
>
> Once you have had a look around the Exodus wallet and you like it, it is time to go through the backup. During the backup process you will receive your (randomly generated) secret phrase of your wallet. This is a secret phrase that functions as a master key to all of your assets, if you would like to know more about your secret phrase then please check out this article: [12-word secret “recovery phrase”](https://support.exodus.io/article/925-everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-12-word-recovery-phrase)

If the password to the wallet doesn't work and you haven't transferred money to the wallet then you can probably just start again.